# Further request(s) expected leaving 1 unsatisfied expectation(s). 0 request(s) executed

Tags: java, spring, rest, testing

I have following test class for my spring-integration application.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:/test-dao-rest.xml"})
public class TestEmployeeRestDao {

  @Autowired
  private EmployeeDao employeeRestDao;

  @Autowired
  private RestTemplate mockRestTemplate;

  private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

  /**
   * Sets up.
   */
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(mockRestTemplate).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void testGetEmployeeById() {
    when(mockRestTemplate.getForObject(url + 1, Employee.class)).thenReturn(emp2);
    mockServer.expect(times(1), requestTo(url + 1))
        .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
    Employee employee = employeeRestDao.getEmployeeById(1L);
    assertNotNull(employee);
    mockServer.verify();
  }
```

`}

My xml config

```
  <bean class="com.nikolay.client.handler.CustomResponseErrorHandler"
    id="customResponseErrorHandler"/>

  <bean class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock" id="mockRestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg value="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate"/>
    <property name="messageConverters">
      <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="customResponseErrorHandler"/>
  </bean>

  <bean class="com.nikolay.client.EmployeeRestDaoImpl" id="employeeRestDao">
    <property name="restTemplate" ref="mockRestTemplate"/>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

When I run a test, an error is thrown. Who can say what is wrong? I could not understand why this error occurs.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Further request(s) expected leaving 1 unsatisfied expectation(s).
0 request(s) executed.
```

Can you please help me to find out how this issue can be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

`mockRestTemplate` is Autowired here. It is not a mock. Do not use `when(<>>).thenReturn(<<>>)` on it.

Annotate it with `@MockBean` than `@Autowired` incase the template is a bean.